# What is the synonym of this array in Obj-C

Tags: objective-c, arrays

What is the synonym of this array in Obj-C?

```
int month[12] = {31,0,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can freely use c array in your objective-c code. But if you really need to use objective-c typed array you will have the following (note that objective-c containers can only hold objective-c type objects):

```
NSArray *month = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:31],
                                           [NSNumber numberWithInt:0],
                                           ...
                                           [NSNumber numberWithInt:31], nil];
```

Comment: hi it has this error: expected expression before '{' token when i use c code

Comment: no, it must be correct anyway... if you write NSInteger month[12]; (is there really semicolon in the end?) then where you use initializer list?

Comment: yes semicolon in the end of [12] / at viewController.m file / month = {31,0,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};

Comment: i want month be an int to use it NOT array whit *

Comment: I see... you can initialize array this way only if you declare it in the same line. if you declare it in another place you will need to assign each element separately

Answer (score 2):

Objective-C is a superset of C so the array you propose can be used in Objective-C code.

If you're interested in using Objective-C data structures, I'd start with an `NSArray` of `NSNumber` instances and work from there.